# Reduce Lists to Lists of common elements efficiently

Tags: java, scala

I have a List of Lists containing Integer values. Actually List could be every other collection type too. I want a new List of Lists, with the inner Lists containing all Integer values of any List, linked by such value.

Imagine e.g. a queue A, the first List contains 31 and 43, which are now in the queue. A is compared with the next Lists. If value of A exists in the List, the other values are appended too.

e.g.:

```
Input:
    [[31,43],
    [18,397],
    [19,18,31],
    [18,99],
    [7,2]]

Output:

    [[31,43,18,397,19,99],
    [7,2]]
```

The simplest but probably not very efficient approach would be to loop over each List, creating a queue like variable and check if Lists contain a common value. It would require many loops. One problem is, every time values are added, the previous Lists would need to be rechecked, as there are new values to consider. It would have to be applied for each new List too.

As there are many functions to consider i wonder which method is the most efficient. If this problem has a special function or is well known under another name, i would also be glas to know. Thanks all.

Comment: I am not sure what do you mean by "linked in the input", but you checking if some value exist could be done using operations on `Set`s. Do you mean "group together lists that have at least 1 common element"?

Comment: Or in other words, take sets of values that may overlap, and compute set of minimal disjoint sets containing all of these sets?

Comment: Thanks, if tried to explain the problem more precise. Yes i want to compute a set of minimal disjoint sets, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If I understood correctly:

- you have set of sets of values,
- these sets may overlap
- if they do, you want to minimize it so that sets with overlapping values are combined
- your values are always integers

If so, then this could be done rather fast with `BitSet`s:

```
import scala.collection.immutable.BitSet
def combine(inputs: Set[BitSet]): Set[BitSet] =
  inputs.foldLeft(Set.empty[BitSet]) { (result, input) =>
    val connected = result.filter(set => (set & input).nonEmpty)
    if (connected.isEmpty) result + input
    else (result &~ connected) + connected.foldLeft(input)(_ | _)
  }

combine(
  Set(
    BitSet(31,43),
    BitSet(18,397),
    BitSet(19,18,31),
    BitSet(18,99),
    BitSet(7,2)
  )
)
// Set(BitSet(18, 19, 31, 43, 99, 397), BitSet(2, 7))

// alternative conditionless implementation
def combine(inputs: Set[BitSet]): Set[BitSet] =
  inputs.foldLeft(Set.empty[BitSet]) { (result, input) =>
    val (disjoint, connected) = result.partition(set => (set & input).isEmpty)
    disjoint + connected.foldLeft(input)(_ | _)
  }
```

Comment: Worked for me, thank you! Could there be an additional performance improvement using e.g. Streams or would you think this is basically the most efficient solution?

Comment: (Reactive) Streams or any sort of parallelism has a cost. Unless running everything sequentially is more expensive than doing something in parallel/lazily there is no point for using them. And that happens more often in IO-bounded operations than CPU-bounded like this one. You'd have to have a looooot of sets to justify using RS and/or laziness and/or parallelism. And BitSet is the cheapest set for Ints that I am aware of.